# How to project tiling brush in sculpting to normal

Tags: sculpting

[image: Tiled Draw Brush]

I'm trying to draw lines on a plane that has a bulge near the bottom, but the tile sculpting brush does not change on the x-axis and is based on the cursor brush. Is it possible to have all duplicated brushes project to the surface of the object for consistent lines across the plane?